Subscribing to topic /tf_static in ROS2
I am trying to subscribe to the topics /tf and /tf_static.
/tf works now but I am not getting any data from /tf_static.
Can I even subscribe to the topic?
TF_Subscriber::TF_Subscriber(const Create3_Config* config, const std::string& node_name)
    : Node(node_name), create3_config(config)
{
    // /tf[tf2_msgs / msg / TFMessage]
    tf_subscription_call = this->create_subscription<tf2_msgs::msg::TFMessage>(
        (std::string(create3_config->ros_namespace) + "/tf").c_str(),
        rclcpp::SensorDataQoS(),
        std::bind(&TF_Subscriber::tfCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    if (!tf_subscription_call)
        printf("Failed to create subscription for /tf topic");
    else
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Subscription for /tf topic created successfully");

    // /tf_static[tf2_msgs / msg / TFMessage]
    tf_static_subscription_call = this->create_subscription<tf2_msgs::msg::TFMessage>(
        (std::string(create3_config->ros_namespace) + "/tf_static").c_str(),
        rclcpp::SensorDataQoS(),
        std::bind(&TF_Subscriber::tf_staticCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    if (!tf_static_subscription_call)
        printf("Failed to create subscription for /tf_static topic");
    else
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Subscription for /tf_static topic created successfully");
}

void TF_Subscriber::tfCallback(const tf2_msgs::msg::TFMessage::SharedPtr tf_msg)
{
    auto timestamp = tf_msg->transforms[0].header.stamp;

    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "TF Timestamp: %f",
        timestamp.sec + timestamp.nanosec * 1e-9
    );
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "transform, rotation: X:%f, Y:%f, Z:%f, W:%f",
        tf_msg->transforms[0].transform.rotation.x,
        tf_msg->transforms[0].transform.rotation.y,
        tf_msg->transforms[0].transform.rotation.z,
        tf_msg->transforms[0].transform.rotation.w
    );
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "transform, translation: X:%f, Y:%f, Z:%f",
        tf_msg->transforms[0].transform.translation.x,
        tf_msg->transforms[0].transform.translation.y,
        tf_msg->transforms[0].transform.translation.z
    );
}

void TF_Subscriber::tf_staticCallback(const tf2_msgs::msg::TFMessage::SharedPtr tf_static_msg)
{
    auto timestamp = tf_static_msg->transforms[0].header.stamp;

    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "TF Static Timestamp: %f",
        timestamp.sec + timestamp.nanosec * 1e-9
    );
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "transform, rotation: X:%f, Y:%f, Z:%f, W:%f",
        tf_static_msg->transforms[0].transform.rotation.x,
        tf_static_msg->transforms[0].transform.rotation.y,
        tf_static_msg->transforms[0].transform.rotation.z,
        tf_static_msg->transforms[0].transform.rotation.w
    );
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "transform, translation: X:%f, Y:%f, Z:%f",
        tf_static_msg->transforms[0].transform.translation.x,
        tf_static_msg->transforms[0].transform.translation.y,
        tf_static_msg->transforms[0].transform.translation.z
    );
}


/tf_static is published with transient local durability. By default you create subscribers with volatile durability. To change that do:
rclcpp::QoS qos(10);
 qos.durability(rclcpp::DurabilityPolicy::TransientLocal);

node_->create_subscription(topic, qos, callback_function, options);
```

